# TypeScript - Validate object properties with HOC

Tags: typescript, graphql

I have a context interface that looks like this:

```
export interface IReq extends Request {
  user?: IUser;
}

export interface IContext {
  req: IReq;
  res: Response;
}
```

I have an isAuthenticated HOC that wraps revolvers:

```
import { IContext } from "generic";

export default (next: Function) => <R, A, I>(root: R, args: A, context: IContext, info: I) => {
    if (!context.req.user) {
        throw new Error(`Unauthenticated!`);
    }

    return next(root, args, context, info);
};
```

The function checks to make sure the user is available, if it's not it will throw an error.

When I wrap my resolver in the HOC, TypeScript still complains that context.req.user may be undefined.

```
import isAuthenticated from '../../utils/isAuthenticated';

export default {
    Add: isAuthenticated((
      _: null,
      { input }: { input: AddInput },
      context: IContext
    ) => {
        return Controller.add({ ...input }, context.req.user);
    })
};
```

context.req.user can't be undefined because the isAuthenticated HOC will throw an error before it even calls the child function.

Is there a way a better way to structure this?

Answer (score 0):

The typescript compiler can only be so smart.

If you are super duper ultra sure that value cannot be `null` or `undefined` due your own application logic, then you can tell Typescript that by adding a `!` to the end of your expression.

Contrived example:

```
let foo: string | null = null
function setFoo() { foo = 'a,b,c' }
setFoo()
console.log(foo!.split(','))
//             ^ here
```

or in your case:

```
context.req.user!
```

But use that sparingly, because if you're wrong, and there could be a null there, you will likely throw an exception.